# Python Flask flask-admin wtforms.validators AttributeError

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, attributeerror, flask-admin

Im going through Flask based tutorial "Learn flask framework" by Matt Copperwaite and now am  stuck in following error.
After adding Flask-Admin I started to build admin dashboard with it. I tried to add Fileadmin module to control static files:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.fileadmin import FileAdmin
```

And now I'm getting next error, after trying to access corresponding web-form:

```
[2021-12-15 14:14:32,563] ERROR in app: Exception on /admin/blogfileadmin/ [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/fileadmin/__init__.py", line 812, in index_view
    delete_form = self.delete_form()
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/fileadmin/__init__.py", line 495, in delete_form
    delete_form_class = self.get_delete_form()
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/fileadmin/__init__.py", line 425, in get_delete_form
    class DeleteForm(self.form_base_class):
  File "/home/demino/WebProjects/blog/blog/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/fileadmin/__init__.py", line 426, in DeleteForm
    path = fields.HiddenField(validators=[validators.Required()])
AttributeError: module 'wtforms.validators' has no attribute 'Required'
```

I already experienced a bunch of problems caused by book being published in 2015, but so far I managed to solve them quite fast. Now Im stuck and cant find information that could help.

Thanks in advance.

Edit1: Solved - manually changed `validators.required()` call to `validators.DataRequired()` in flask-admin -> fileadmin **init**.py . They distinguished them in v1.0.2 (https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes/#version-1-0-2). Not sure though which exactly, Data- or Input- requirement is correct here. Will see.

Comment: To follow stack overflow Q/A you should move your solution to an answer instead, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved - manually changed `validators.required()` call to `validators.DataRequired()` in flask-admin -> fileadmin init.py . They distinguished them in v1.0.2 (https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes/#version-1-0-2).